# TypeScript complex conditional type

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a factory. I need to pass to the factory a method and I need to change the type of **this** (inside the method) depending on some options.

Here is my attempt using *conditional types* and what I need to achieve.

```js
function foo<
    O extends { func?: (this: T) => void; str?: boolean},
    T extends (O extends { str: true } ? { id: string } : { id: number })
>(opts?: O) {}

foo({ func: function() { this.id = 0; } });              // Ok
foo({ func: function() { this.id = 0; }, str: true });   // Ok, but I want to be in error
foo({ func: function() { this.id = "0"; }, str: true }); // Error, but I want to be ok
```

I know I can achieve this target with *overloads* and that's the solution I'm using ATM, ...

```js
function bar<O extends { func?: (this: T) => void; str: true}, T extends { id: string }>(opts?: O);
function bar<O extends { func?: (this: T) => void; str?: boolean}, T extends { id: number }>(opts?: O);
function bar<O extends { func?: (this: T) => void; str?: boolean}, T extends ({ id: string } | { id: number })>(opts?: O) {}

bar({ func: function() { this.id = 0; } });              // Ok
bar({ func: function() { this.id = 0; }, str: true });   // Ok: error
bar({ func: function() { this.id = "0"; }, str: true }); // Ok
```

... but since in the real case the type of **this** needs to depend on several options, the result is a terrible block of code repetition with two frustrating drawbacks:

1. each time I need to add another option on which the type of **this** need to depends, I have to **double!** the overloads increasing even more the code repetition;
2. each time I have to change something in my factory, I need to apply the same change to dozens of overloads

I also know that an alternative solution could be to extract the method outside the options Object, but...

```js
function baz<
    O extends { str?: boolean },
    T extends (O extends { str: true } ? { id: string } : { id: number })
>(func?: (this: T) => void, opts?: O) {}

baz(function() { this.id = 0; });                  // Ok
baz(function() { this.id = 0; }, { str: true });   // Ok: error
baz(function() { this.id = "0"; }, { str: true }); // Ok
```

but since the type of **this** needs to depend on the presence of some methods in the options Object, this is not applicable.

I definitively need to improve my code removing all that code repetition.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false#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-UKmHaxQ6xE6Za7VO6dF6fQnBbMYsEwhEAD7+QMJJIpfphw2RwrFElYC0qWa1QGm+rLBhgjqibq9I7DUcncb4YltjsAhZm3vNMXgwdbZXwhWIgZ4U6T9jJL4-VuUmfzWrz0FLgeIKEw7ZyhFeJHjyYlLCnABycCueiyWW0MAgPQNF0JRWXZBAYzNHkAC9MBwPArUTFxs3YD1dAMbYzDwX0BVsDhEMFZD5Q8R9fErTU5R1CIogCCigxrVJ0g4YV2FFPg0ylZ1KB2A0IwIJtXwtaDmK5EEVkvDYV16Lcx1kncpz0YSzx7C82ivVcdiIh8R1weS93RQ8hJE7sxL7CTIWhWF-HXEiR3k18gA).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAv9PW) meet your needs (please test against use cases)? If so I could write up an answer.  If not, please [edit] the example code to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz , interesting! I'll do some try to check if this approach can help me.